# Undo file removed by rm commend on MAC terminal

Tags: rm

I unfortunately deleted `.bash_profile` file from my MAC. Accidentally I typed `rm .bash_profile`. Now how can I get my file back?

Comment: Ok, I just solved the problem from time machine back up

Answer (score 2):

UNLESS you have fine backups (in this case your timemachine) you are really out of luck.

Comment: I solved the problem from time machine back up and I wrote above in my comment.